# Testing Spring REST services with Arquillian - ClassNotFoundException JspServlet

Tags: java, spring, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to set up a simple Arquillian test for REST service written with Spring. Here is my SpringBoot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity test() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello world");
    }
}
```

then I want to test it running Arquillian test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestControllerTest {
    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        File[] files = Maven.resolver()
                .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                .importRuntimeDependencies()
                .resolve().withTransitivity()
                .asFile();
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addPackage(pl.fuv.Application.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(TestController.class.getPackage())
                .addAsLibraries(files);
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void callRest(@ArquillianResteasyResource final WebTarget webTarget) {
        Response response = webTarget.path("/test").request().get();
        String result = response.readEntity(String.class);
        assertEquals("Hello world", result);
    }
}
```

During deployment I get runtime exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet [jsp] in web application
>   [/0a1cee74-c798-46af-9402-474168676ae6] threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

and Arquillian gets 404 HTTP response calling the service:

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:  Expected :Hello world Actual
>   :HTTP Status 404 – Not
>   Found (...)

My guess is that I build deployment artifact in a wrong way, that is missing something, but I could not find any info what might be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-spring ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dependency on jasper:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.32</version>
</dependency>
```